# How can I get textbox text from Blank Page to MainPage?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I want to get the text from blankpage.xaml to Mainpage.xaml

I try to use this on MainPage.xaml:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  enter.Text = (App.Current as App).trytext;
}
```

but there is an error that trytext could not found so i use and if statement:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) 
{
        if (enter.Text == "")
        {
            enter.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            enter.Text = (App.Current as App).trytext;
        }
}
```

But when I get the text from blankpage there is no text when I get back to mainpage

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it seems like you're trying to creating a variable that's accessible through the whole application?

If you want to pass some data from page 1 to page 2, you can pass the information in the Navigate method.

Probably you're calling something like

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

The Navigate method has an extra parameter in which you can pass your info. Call it like `Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), enter.Text);`

In the OnNavigatedTo you can get the value from the NavigationEventArgs.
probably something like:

```
enter.Text = e.Parameter.ToString();
```